# Read and Write in Windows Phone (Universal) application

Tags: c#, file, windows-phone-8.1, local-storage

Whether it is possible to write the text in the file that was created in the project directory. Read the file I did it, but the record can somehow? Or it is necessary to create a file via code?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/jj681698(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is very possible to write a text file via code.
First, create a model of how your file content will be saved e.g

```
public class Person
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
}
```

Then this is your code for saving the above model to your local text file after serializing the object to a string. Use json.Net to do that

```
private void AddPerson(Person person)
{        
        //save
        var mystream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync("file.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(mystream))
        {
            var x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
            writer.Write(x);
        }
}
```

This is very easy and fast. Hope it helps

Comment: and you can add text to a file that has already been created in the project? not in local storage, and the draft